# Remove get parameter from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, content-management-system

i have friendly urls enabled on my site (its a custom cms) but sometimes when i click on the link from an outer link, it displays the "perf" text repeated with ?perf= after the first parameter of the url.

for example if my normal url is

https://www.example.com/friendlyurl

it displays

https://www.example.com/friendlyurl?perf=friendlyurl

here is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?perf=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)HOME(.*)$ /$1$2 [L,R=301]
```

I need to remove the ?perf=friendlyurl section, i have tried several ways changing the htaccess with no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I prefer using a URI approach to pretty URLs, this is common in most CMS, what it is is the part of the url after the  `.php`  so `www.domain.com/index.php/{URI PATH}` then using `$_SERVER` you can route them ( get that path and split it up etc. ), and use Htaccess to remove the `index.php` bit.

Comment: This method has the added benefit of still allowing you to use `$_GET` for say a search form, and avoids all the complicated htaccess rules.  If you look at how CodeIgniter 2.0 does there routing, that's what I mean.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Thanks for your answer, actually the CMS was built by someone else, i have managed to do some small changes to the htaccess code, but everytime there is a 301 involved it somehow puts the perf= thing after the friendly url, so for example if someone posts in adwords the url when you do click from the add it shows the perf bit after the url because its being redirected since the htaccess has a redirection from http:// to https://